# How to access variables from parent class to child class?

Tags: python

```
class Approxalumni():
    def __init__(self, year_est, currnt_intake):
        self.year_est=year_est
        self.currnt_intake=currnt_intake
        t1 = PrettyTable(['Established year', "<1960", "1960-1980", "1980-2000", "2000-2010", "2010-2018"])
        t1.add_row(["", "10%", '10%', '20%', '50%', '100%'])
        if year_est<=1960:
            t1.add_row(['',abs((currnt_intake/100)*10),'','','',''])
            print(t1)
            s1= (abs((currnt_intake/100)*10))
            print("Total Approximate alumni strength is:"+ str(s1))
        else:
            pass


class Reg_approx(Approxalumni):
    def reg(self):
        t2= PrettyTable(['Approximate Registration', "Year-1", "Year-2", "Year-3", "Year-4", "Year-5"])
        #t2.add_row(["", 1%((Approxalumni.s1)/100), '10%', '20%', '50%','100%'])
        #t2.add_row(["", 1 % ((Approxalumni.s4) / 100), '10%', '20%', '50%', '100%'])
        print(t2)


Approxalumni(
    year_est=int(input("Enter Established year of the institute:")),
    currnt_intake=int(input("enter current intake of Institute:"))
)
```

I want to use "s1" in child class to do some calculations and print it in table
what is the method to use variables from the parent class in child class?

Comment: `s1` is a local variable in a function and is only available in that function. Make it an instance attribute (`self.s1`) if you want to have it persist in any way beyond `__init__`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all:

Approxalumni() = parent class

Reg_approx() = child class

Your inheriting all functions and variables from Approxalumni() when calling it in this way. So to access s1, you simply have to assign it to self:

```
self.s1 = (abs((currnt_intake/100)*10))
```

From then on you can simply call self.s1 as the variable you want in both the parent and child classes.

Comment: @marangmax I am not getting how to write it in child class can u help?

Comment: Have you tried  reading up on the concepts of Object Oriented Programming? Like, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm

Comment: @mightybeard In the child class, as long as your inheriting from the parent class, you can simply call it as self.s1. If you want to understand fully what's going on, and what's next you should consider doing some more reading